# How can I find generic invocations with a specific type argument in my source?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have a generic method

```
public void Foo<T>(T arg) where T : ISomeInterface
```

This method is used quite a lot throughout the code, and I want to find where it is used with T being a specific type.

I can text-search for

```
"Foo<TheType>("
```

but most often the type argument has been omitted from the call (inferred). 
Is there any way I can find these method invocations in VS2010 or perhaps ReSharper?

Comment: JetBrains comments on [this similar/related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-183453) suggest this isn't currently available. It looks to me as though Structural Search and Replace *should* be able to do it, but I can't seem to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the next version of ReSharper, this will be covered by "Search with Pattern" feature.
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-288080

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly get the compiler to help you find them using the old break-it-and-and-see-what-doesn't-compile approach: if the type T in question is your own code, try changing its definition so that it no longer implements ISomeInterface.

Answer (score 0):

Run the assembly through ildasm and search for the appropriate method signature, then work backwards through the disassembly to get source file and line number.

Comment: That works. On the other hand, I already have an FxCop rule that tells me where these calls are. I am just curious if I can do this faster/easier than that (i.e., directly in source).

Answer (score 0):

I tried following ReSharper search pattern (ReSharper->Tools->PatternCatalog->Add Pattern):

Search pattern: Foo($arg$)
Placeholder: arg = expression which is of type TheType

Then save it and click "Search now".

Comment: Does that work? What version of ReSharper? Is it the "next" version Evgeny talked about in his answer? I only have R# 5.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily declare non-generic method and find its usages.

```
public void Foo(TheType arg)
{
}
```

After the declaration it is preferred method instead of generic.

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned you can use text search for "`Foo<TheType>(`" and "`Foo(TheType`" where it is inferred

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: there are hundreds of different types passed as T, and it can be inferred most of the time what type it is. I want to find calls where T is one specific type.